#atlas how to specify inline datum present when consuming an input utxo?
I've just started using Atlas and cannot find any info on how to specify in GYTxInWitnessScript that the input to be validated has inline datum (so I shouldn't have to provide it explicitly). Would Nothing work?
I'm basically looking for the equivalent of cardano-cli's "inline-datum-present"
